# I was running a test on my signal.py file and i am getting 'ValueError: seek of closed file' error

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

here is the signals.py file inside main app
[image]

and here is the test_signals.py file enter image description here[image]

the full error is
[image]

Comment: Please post actual codes, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Your `models.ProductImage` is just storing the file handle, and only opens the file later.  However, you create file handle in a `with` statement.  You don't try to use that file handle until the `with` statement exits, at which point the file is closed.  That's the purpose of `with`.

`with` is convenient, but you have to understand how object ownership flows.  You either need to skip the `with` and just do `f = open(...)`, or move the `image.save()` inside the `with`, or just pass the file name and let the object open the file.